# Switching to Evernote from Emacs

Tags: emacs, evernote

I have been using Emacs in orgmode with Dropbox for organising many of my files and I am thinking of switching to Evernote. I would beinterested to hear if anyone else has made the switch and to hear about their experiences before I make a decision.

Comment: I am about to do the same and would be every interested in your findings.